# Excel VBA Create Dropdown List on Cell based on Worksheetnames

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create a dropdownlist based on worksheetnames.

```
Worksheets("MainSheet").Range("A1").Select

With Selection.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:= ***WorkSheetnames***
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With
```

So where `***WorkSheetnames***` is, I wanted to put all worksheetnames

Maybe something with

```
for i = 1 to application.sheets.count 
'Store data into array?
Names = sheets(i).name
next
```

How can I do this without adding a sheet or something..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are almost near goal

Before your code add

```
Dim Shts As String
    For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
        Shts = Shts & ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Name & ","
    Next
    Shts = Left(Shts, Len(Shts) - 1)
```

then within validation make

```
Formula1:=Shts
```